# Why is flex the best choice for handling mathematical content? (a question about approach0)

Tags: parsers

This questions is about the work [A novel similarity-search method for mathematical content in LaTeX markup and its implementation](http://tkhost.github.io/opmes/thesis-ref.pdf).

Mr. Wei Zhong uses [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) lexer generator.

Now, supose I find an expression like $\pi(x)$, the [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

How to represent the prime-counting function correctly and not interpret $\pi$ as the number $3.14159$?

Answer (score 1):

The lexer doesn't interpret anything. It just separates the input into tokens. It's up to the parser to decide what the syntactic rôle of π is in that input.

It's possible that the thesis discusses that question; I didn't read it from end to end. But as far as I can see, the thesis never claims that the parsing tools used are "the best"; presumably, the author chose to use those particular tools because they were familiar with them, and saw how to apply them to the problem at hand. Moreover, the goal of the thesis is not to analyse arbitrary mathematical expressions in some abstract syntax; it is to analyse mathematical expressions written in LaTeX, and so the lexical analysis is, for better or worse, LaTeX specific.

Note that the "problem at hand" does not require accurate parsing of mathematical expressions. Wei's goal was to mine a large corpus for mathematical equations *similar to* a given search pattern, for some definition of "similarity". Presumably, in order to cope with the vagaries of mathematical expressions, the function application $f(\pi/2)$ is considered at least somewhat similar to the product $f\times(\pi/2)$.